# META-INF/context.xml file for Tomcat and Glassfish

Tags: tomcat, glassfish, context.xml

As you know we can manage our JNDI lookup resources with a file named context.xml in our meta-inf when we are deploy the war module on Tomcat.

But what we can do the same thing in Glassfish? How to write our JNDI lookup config in our project not directly in glassfish context files? because I dont want to depend on app-server I want to have the project's config inside the project.

RGDS

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `sun-web.xml`. This is GF-specific war deployment descriptor which, among other options, allows to define and override JNDI lookups.